# How to create a registration form for dealers in drupal7

Tags: drupal-7

I want to create a registration form for dealers in my drupal website.Can any one suggest best way to create a registration form where  'dealers' can register with details, address,contact no etc and upon site admin approval, a user name/ password to be
issued by the site admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the user sign-up form itself? You can add fields to the User profile under Configuration->People->Account Settings->Manage Fields, and mark them for inclusion on the new user form. You can then set accounts to require admin activation. That way, a user can create a new account, but it won't be active until the admin approves.

I would also create a user role called "dealer" and give that role the permissions you decide are appropriate, and assign that role to dealers when you approve them.

Hope that gets you started.